# Convert string to GUID with sscanf

Tags: c++, c, guid, scanf

I'm trying to convert a string to GUID with sscanf:

```
GUID guid;
sscanf( "11111111-2222-3333-4455-667788995511", "%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
        &guid.Data1, &guid.Data2, &guid.Data3,
        &guid.Data4[0], &guid.Data4[1], &guid.Data4[2],
        &guid.Data4[3], &guid.Data4[4], &guid.Data4[5],
        &guid.Data4[6], &guid.Data4[7]);
```

However, in runtime, it fails and exits with "Error: Command failed". Why? How to fix it?

I do not want to compile with /clr so cannot use `System`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where does "Error: Command failed" come from? It's not a standard error message...

You can use the [UuidFromString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379336%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to do it in native C++.

Comment: I'm coding in haXe targeting c++, so maybe the error is from the haXe testing program... But the code in the question is in pure c++.

When I use `UuidFromString("11111111-2222-3333-4455-667788995511",&guid);` it says `error C2664: 'UuidFromStringA' : cannot convert parameter 1 fr
om 'const char *' to 'RPC_CSTR'` ...

Comment: @Billy: True, but he said he didn't want to use "/clr" which is also Windows-only, so I thought that was an OK assumption to make.

Comment: @Andy: I believe a simple cast would work: `const char *str = "..."; UuidFromString((RPC_CSTR) str, &guid);`

Answer (score 9):

I think you are damaging the stack. X type specifier requires pointer to int which is at least 4 bytes, so starting from &guid.Data[4] parameter you've screwed up. Provide enough space for sscanf and you should be fine. Final code looks like this:

```
    GUID guid;

    unsigned long p0;
    int p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10;

    int err = sscanf_s(s.c_str(), "%08lX-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        &p0, &p1, &p2, &p3, &p4, &p5, &p6, &p7, &p8, &p9, &p10);

    guid.Data1 = p0;
    guid.Data2 = p1;
    guid.Data3 = p2;
    guid.Data4[0] = p3;
    guid.Data4[1] = p4;
    guid.Data4[2] = p5;
    guid.Data4[3] = p6;
    guid.Data4[4] = p7;
    guid.Data4[5] = p8;
    guid.Data4[6] = p9;
    guid.Data4[7] = p10;
```

Answer (score 4):

Working & not damaging the stack:

```cpp
GUID guid;

sscanf_s(AliasName.c_str(), "{%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX}",
        &guid.Data1, &guid.Data2, &guid.Data3,
        &guid.Data4[0], &guid.Data4[1], &guid.Data4[2],
        &guid.Data4[3], &guid.Data4[4], &guid.Data4[5],
        &guid.Data4[6], &guid.Data4[7]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 and C99 are out there, it is now possible to parse a GUID string  right into the GUID structure, using [argument size specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) such as e. g. `hh` which stands for a single byte data. However, the correct and portable way that does not depend on the platform sizes of `long`, `int` and `short` is to use macros provided in [`<inttypes.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes) (or `<cinttypes>` for C++11):

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#define G32 "%8" SCNx32
#define G16 "%4" SCNx16
#define G8  "%2" SCNx8

bool to_guid(const char* str, GUID* guid) {
  int nchars = -1;
  int nfields =
    sscanf(str, "{" G32 "-" G16 "-" G16 "-" G8 G8 "-" G8 G8 G8 G8 G8 G8 "}%n",
           &guid->Data1, &guid->Data2, &guid->Data3,
           &guid->Data4[0], &guid->Data4[1], &guid->Data4[2], &guid->Data4[3],
           &guid->Data4[4], &guid->Data4[5], &guid->Data4[6], &guid->Data4[7],
           &nchars);
  return nfields == 11 && nchars == 38;
}

#undef G8
#undef G16
#undef G32
```

The macros in the `<inttypes.h>` may be defined differently by different compilers and system bitness; just for the sake of an example, on my system they are defined in `<inttypes.h>` as

```
#define SCNx8        "hhx"
#define SCNx16       "hx"
#define SCNx32       "x"
#define SCNx64       "llx"
```

The `%n` specifier at the end returns the length of the string parsed "so far", so if the string is missing the trailing `}`, `%n` would not be reached, and `nchars` will have the initial value of -1, otherwise it will return the length of the GUID string, which must be 38 (otherwise, e. g. the last byte may parse even if it is a single hex character, which would be invalid for a GUID). The `%n` itself is not counted as a "field" for the purposes of `sscanf`'s return value.

This is still not fantastically correct, as the parser accepts spaces in lieu of leading zeroes for each component, so that the string with strategically placed spaces

```
{  FACFFB-   C-4DF3-A06C-D4 1 A 2 B 3}
```

will still parse as if it was

```
{00FACFFB-000C-4DF3-A06C-D4010A020B03}
```

but this is probably as far as one can get with a single `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CLSIDFromString if you want to avoid RPCRT4.DLL dependency - CLSID is simply a GUID, so it will work despite the slightly confusing name.

Comment: 'Fraid it will revert looking for a ProgID string in the registry if the UUID is not in the proper format (`IIDFromString()` will not, though, but requires curlies). Also, there is only a widechar version of it. Unless using COM, I would not go with it (and you'd get a dependency of OLE2.DLL instead of RPCRT4, which is not a fair exchange either). Raymond Chen has more: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151015-00/?p=91351